# Pass same Props to multiple React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I'm currently rendering two different components based on the value of `shouldRenderPlanA` - however, despite different components being rendered (depending on the value) - I pass both the same props. How can I condense this to reduce repeated code?

```
return (
  <>
    {options.map(option)}
    <StyledRow>
      {variousOptions.map((opt) => (
        shouldRenderPlanA ? (
          <StyledLabelOptionOne
            variousProps={variousProps}
            variousProps={variousProps}
            variousProps={variousProps}
          />
        ) : (
          <StyledLabelOptionTwo
            variousProps={variousProps}
            variousProps={variousProps}
            variousProps={variousProps}
          />
        )
      ))}
    </StyledRow>
  </>
);
```

Comment: Do you want to reduce repeated code where you have repeated props?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could assign both options to a variable which contains a union of both component types.

Combining and then spreading the props from an object may also be beneficial, depending on where those props come from. If they are taken from `opt` inside the map then this second step is probably not required:

```
const LabelComponent = shouldRenderPlanA ? StyledLabelOptionOne : StyledLabelOptionTwo;

return (
  <>
    {options.map(option)}
    <StyledRow>
      {variousOptions.map((opt) => (
        <LabelComponent
          prop1={opt.prop1}
          prop2={opt.prop2}
        />
      ))}
    </StyledRow>
  </>
);
```

Comment: shouldRenderPlanA is not dependant on opt - but some of the props are!

Comment: @cts OK, well with that in mind, I have edited in what I think is the optimal solution for your use case. It is likely still possible to destructure the props out of `opt` using a `...rest` so you can spread them, but I would need to see more implementation details.

Answer (score 8):

To pass same Props to multiple React component or to pass multiple Props to a React component, you can use Object [unpacking/destruction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment?retiredLocale=it) within components.

```
function Component() {
  const propPack = {
    variousProps1: variousProps1,
    variousProps2: variousProps2,
    variousProps3: variousProps3,
  };

  return (
    <>
      {options.map(option)}
      <StyledRow>
        {variousOptions.map((opt) => (
          shouldRenderPlanA
            ? <StyledLabelOptionOne {...propPack} />
            : <StyledLabelOptionTwo {...propPack} />
        ))}
      </StyledRow>
    </>
  );
}
```

This is commonly used to pass all the parent props down to children

```
function Component(props) {
  return (
    condition
      ? <StyledLabelOptionOne {...props} />
      : <StyledLabelOptionTwo {...props} />
  )
}
```

You can also conditionally pick the component for rendering (but this IMHO is less readable)

```
function Component() {
  const PickedComponent = shouldRenderPlanA ? StyledLabelOptionOne : StyledLabelOptionTwo;
  return (
    <>
      {options.map(option)}
      <StyledRow>
        {variousOptions.map((opt) => (
          <PickedComponent
            variousProps1={variousProps1}
            variousProps2={variousProps2}
            variousProps3={variousProps3}
          />
        ))}
      </StyledRow>
    </>
  );
}
```

For conditions/props derived from within `.map()` simply move the code within the map callback

```
function Component() {
  return (
    <>
      {options.map(option)}
      <StyledRow>
        {variousOptions.map((opt) => {
          const propPack = {
            variousProps1: variousProps1,
            variousProps2: opt.value,
          };
          const PickedComponent = opt.condition ? StyledLabelOptionOne : StyledLabelOptionTwo;
          return (
            shouldRenderPlanA
              ? <StyledLabelOptionOne {...propPack} />
              : <StyledLabelOptionTwo {...propPack} />
          )
        })}
      </StyledRow>
    </>
  );
}
```

*Note how arrow function within map has becomed an arrow function with a complete block. From `(opt) => (first_instruction)` to `(opt) => { first_instruction; return (second_instruction); }`. This allows us to add code before rendering at each `map()` cycle.*

Comment: That's a neat solution.

Comment: thanks. that's a great answer. one outstanding query I have is on how we handle props that make use of the value of "option" in the map? Declaring as an object above means it doesn't have access to the map?

Comment: @cts - the beauty of React stays in the fact that is simple a pure `js` so you can do the same tricks. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the React [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). This would enable you to share the props across multiple children without passing it to each one of them explicitly.

Comment: Indeed a Context provider can work, but IMHO it is overkill. Furthermore, it adds unnecessary complexity and overhead. Here a conditional component switching is attempted.